# Why does this html code give me an error?

Tags: jquery, html

This the index.cshtml file

```
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Vishwaprani Healing Centre";
    }

    <body>
        <div id="wowslider-container1">
            <div class="ws_images">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider6.jpg")" alt="slider6" title="slider6" id="wows1_0" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider1.jpg")" alt="slider1" title="slider1" id="wows1_1" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider2.jpg")" alt="slider2" title="slider2" id="wows1_2" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider3.jpg")" alt="slider3" title="slider3" id="wows1_3" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider4.jpg")" alt="slider4" title="slider4" id="wows1_4" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider5.jpg")" alt="slider5" title="slider5" id="wows1_5" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider7.jpg")" alt="slider7" title="slider7" id="wows1_6" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider8.jpg")" alt="slider8" title="slider8" id="wows1_7" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider9.jpg")" alt="jquery photo gallery" title="slider9" id="wows1_8" /></li>
                    <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/slider10.jpg")" alt="slider10" title="slider10" id="wows1_9" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ws_bullets">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" title="slider6"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb6.jpg")" alt="slider6" />1</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider1"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb1.jpg")" alt="slider1" />2</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider2"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb2.jpg")" alt="slider2" />3</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider3"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb3.jpg")" alt="slider3" />4</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider4"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb4.jpg")" alt="slider4" />5</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider5"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb5.jpg")" alt="slider5" />6</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider7"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb7.jpg")" alt="slider7" />7</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider8"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb8.jpg")" alt="slider8" />8</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider9"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb9.jpg")" alt="slider9" />9</span></a>
                    <a href="#" title="slider10"><span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/thumb10.jpg")" alt="slider10" />10</span></a>
                </div>
            </div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.com">javascript slideshow</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.2</div>
            <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wowslider.js"></script>        
    </body>
```

This is the _Layout.cshtml code==>

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qjQneUBALpjcxghWYEdKnBdnftmBybNA2W5lYqI7y9Q/edit

The problem is when I execute above Index.cshtml which contains a web slider with the given _Layout.cshtml in Visual Studio 2013 it gives me an error like this.==>
[image]
This that function  mentioned in that image which causes the error.==>

```
$("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({ effect: "tv,glass_parallax,parallax,brick,collage,seven,kenburns,cube,blur,book,rotate,domino,slices,blast,blinds,basic,basic_linear,fade,fly,flip,page,stack,stack_vertical", prev: "", next: "", duration: 20 * 100, delay: 20 * 100, width: 1024, height: 768, autoPlay: true, autoPlayVideo: false, playPause: true, stopOnHover: false, loop: false, bullets: 1, caption: true, captionEffect: "parallax", controls: true, controlsThumb: false, responsive: 2, fullScreen: false, gestures: 2, onBeforeStep: 0, images: 0 });
```

This is that .wowSlider method that should be linked to above code==>

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZsZp3XEiAKUdMaE5qbcA6idFW6vU66ivdT1wYLQZ_qY/edit

But when the slider is executed in normal html file it will execute without a problem. ==>

[image]

Is there any modification that needs to be done when the code is executed in an IIS express server?

Comment: have you included the library that contains wowslider? I mean, are you sure it is being loaded?

Comment: I included only the method wowSlider. not the whole library.==>https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZsZp3XEiAKUdMaE5qbcA6idFW6vU66ivdT1wYLQZ_qY/edit

Comment: This the wowslider.js==> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MZoSroTxaEtWS9nd7jcMn9f9xxZnIRsy5DU9Gh9OQHE/edit

Comment: have you included jQuery in the DOM? also I suspect something went serious with loading of wowslider.js.

Comment: Yes. check ==>This is where scripts been imported in the layout.cshtml http://i.imgur.com/KSGzU0b.png     and this is bundle config code  http://i.imgur.com/yyDHEH0.png

Comment: Yes, then the problem is in `script.js`. If you note- your function is defined just before the definition is loaded in `wowslider.js`. Try swapping the locations of both the libraries.

Comment: Man now it's working. Thank you genius. Next time I will be more careful with jquery.

Comment: oh! thanks a lot for the complement. I will put this comment in answer instead for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, The problem as it is usual (order of scripts).

As in the question the function for `wowslider` is called before it had a definition in the DOM.

It needs to be invoked after the library has been loaded.

**Problem-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script> //function called before the library loads.
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wowslider.js"></script> //library loaded after
```

**Solution-**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wowslider.js"></script> //library is loaded first
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

it's a matter of including the right scripts. If you did, check the paths.

Comment: I included the right scripts.  This is the bundleconfig.cs code==> http://i.imgur.com/mxfleid.png as you can see the style.css and jquery library has been bundled. This is where those bundles are imported in to the code in the layout.cs ==>http://i.imgur.com/KSGzU0b.png   . This is where other two libraries imported that needs to execute the slider.  ==>  http://i.imgur.com/9II1q34.png

Comment: This is the the original working html code. Am I missing something?==>https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qHu-iFYLM-yExwr9lX51SIhmU3T4RvLGCGl5r156VHc/edit   .Match that with the the details I have given above.